# Exception of type 'Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.MicrosoftOnlineException' was thrown

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, active-directory, ms-office

I'm using code on http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office365/Office-365-Manage-users-by-cfc96d5e to connect to Office 365 via a test c# web application which basically connects to azure active directory and tries to execute couple of powershell cmdlets.

I'm getting this exception on the Pipeline.Invoke method on the Connect-MsolService cmdlet in my web app:

Exception of type 'Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.MicrosoftOnlineException' was thrown.

So far:

- Followed instructions on this KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2494043
- Installed/enabled the required software (NET Framework 3.5, Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant (64 bit), Microsoft Online Services Module for Windows PowerShell (64 bit))
- set-executionpolicy remotesigned
- using non-federated primary admin account in office cloud to connect remote powershell
- Using a Windows 2008 R2 64 bit machine.
- Targeting 64 bit processor in VS, and .NET framework 4.0
- IIS apppool for this web application is set to use .NET framework 4.0

I can successfully execute connect-msolservice and run cmdlets using the Microsoft Online Services Module for Windows PowerShell on the same machine, using same account.

What else can I try?

Comment: What's the Message within the exception?

Comment: vonPryz, this is actually the Message property of the exception: Exception of type 'Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.MicrosoftOnlineException' was thrown

Answer (score 5):

Change IIS App Pool setting Load User Profile to True

http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/172/p/165426/474632.aspx#474632

Comment: So this solved the issue for me, however, now the commands seem to just fail silently. For example, Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "{username}" -UsageLocation "US" doesn't have any errors, but doesn't actually do anything. When I run the same command directly in powershell it works. Any ideas?

Comment: on top of my head I'd say step into the code (F11 in VS) and inspect your variables? or add a watch? sorry not sure what else you can try. maybe post your question in msoffice forum http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/mso_manage